# SQL Server 2012, only show one row if other exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Question:

I get these results (column `task_externalId`) when I run my query:

- TC229090-10000-3
- TC229090-20000-3
- TC229830-10000-3
- TC229685-10000-3

A task (`TC229090`) can contain multiple rows (10000, 20000), but can also have just one (10000 only).

My full code:

```
SELECT 
    v.voorgemeld_handmatig, v.voorgemeld, v.mac, v.orn, v.cdm, v.blo, 
    v.bco, v.tarcode, (v.timeslotfrom + ' - ' + v.timeslottill),      
    cast (case 
             when 
                (Select ac2.actionSpecificationName 
                 From [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[task] t2 
                 Join [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[actionKind] ak2 On t2.id_actionKind = ak2.id_actionKind 
                 Join [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[actionSpecification] ac2 On ak2.id_actionSpecification = ac2.id_actionSpecification 
                 where t2.task_externalId = (left(t.task_externalId, 15) + '2')) = 'laden' 
                then 'Vol' 
                else 'Leeg' 
          end as text) as IMPORT, 
    t.task_externalId, a.addressName, a.cityName, 
    CONVERT(DATE, t.from_date) as [Date], 
    CONVERT(varchar(8), CONVERT(TIME, t.from_date)) as [Tijd],  
    res.resourceName, resk.resourceKindName, r.shipOwner, 
    t.reference, 
    (Select resourceName 
     From [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[resource] r5 
     Left Outer Join [COMTECdefault].[dbo].resourceKind rk5 On rk5.id_resourceKind = r5.id_resourceKind 
     Where (id_resource = SUBSTRING(pt.StartResources, 0, CHARINDEX(',', pt.StartResources)) 
           or id_resource = PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pt.StartResources, CHARINDEX(',', pt.StartResources) + 1, LEN(pt.StartResources)), ',', '.'), 4) 
           or id_resource = PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pt.StartResources, CHARINDEX(',', pt.StartResources) + 1, LEN(pt.StartResources)), ',', '.'), 3) 
           or id_resource = PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pt.StartResources, CHARINDEX(',', pt.StartResources) + 1, LEN(pt.StartResources)), ',', '.'), 2) 
           or id_resource = PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pt.StartResources, CHARINDEX(',', pt.StartResources) + 1, LEN(pt.StartResources)), ',', '.'), 1)) 
           and r5.id_resourceKind = 51), 
    udo.udf_Gewicht, udo.udf_Zegelnummer, 
    cast (case when a.addressName = 'APM Terminal 2' 
                  then case when udo.udf_Zegelnummer IS NULL 
                               then 0 
                               else 1 
                       end 
               when a.addressName IN ('ect delta', 'Euromax Terminam C.V.', 'Euromax Terminal') 
                  then case when udo.udf_Gewicht = 0 
                               then 0 
                               else 1 
                       end 
               else 1 
          end as bit) as [voormelden],  
    v.foutcode, v.foutcode_tekst, v.V_door 
FROM 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[task] t 
JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[actionKind] ak ON t.id_actionKind = ak.id_actionKind 
JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[actionSpecification] ac ON ak.id_actionSpecification = ac.id_actionSpecification 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[resourceOrder] ro ON t.id_order = ro.id_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[resource] res ON ro.id_resource = res.id_resource 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[resourceKind] resk ON res.id_resourceKind= resk.id_resourceKind 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[address] a ON t.id_address = a.id_address 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[resourceOrder] r ON t.id_order = r.id_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[order] o ON o.id_order = r.id_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[voormelden] v ON v.id_task_otd = t.task_externalId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[ud_order] udo ON udo.id_order = t.id_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[plannedTask] pt on t.id_task = pt.id_task
WHERE
    (pt.id_Task IS NULL OR pt.taskstate <> 'finished') 
    AND (v.canceled IS NULL OR v.canceled = 0) 
    AND left(res.resourceName, 4) <> 'XXXU'  
    AND t.canceled = 0 
    AND (t.from_date <= '2016-11-24 23:59:59') 
    AND (ac.actionSpecificationName = 'inleveren') 
    AND a.addressName IN ('APM Terminal 1','APM Terminal 2', 'ect delta', 'rwg', 'Euromax Terminam C.V.', 'Euromax Terminal') 
ORDER BY 
    res.resourceName, a.addressName, t.task_externalId
```

I only want to show the 20000 task when its exists . Otherwise show the 10000.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those three separated fields or just a long string?

Comment: its a long string.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)-. You should eliminate that `CAST(..... AS TEXT)` ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to touch all of that text there may well be was of narrowing down all of the joins etc, but here is the pattern for doing what you want with the `task_exteralid` column.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (task_externalid VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('TC229090-10000-3')
,('TC229090-20000-3')
,('TC229830-10000-3')
,('TC229685-10000-3')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                    LEFT(task_externalid,CHARINDEX('-',task_externalid) - 1)
                    ORDER BY task_externalid DESC)
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1
```

- Create a partitioned `ROW_NUMBER` on the `LEFT` most portion of the `task_exteralid`
- Order that by `task_exteralid DESC`